# Sketch level curve of $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble with this function. The way I sketch the level curve is to assign constant values and then find out the points where f(x,y) = C.

My problem is that I'm having trouble with algebra since I can't isolate X and Y from C to calculate the level curves in terms of C

$$C = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+1}$$

Comment: $C+Cy^2+Cx^2=x^2$ --> $Cy^2=(1-C)x^2-C$ --> $y^2=\frac{1-C}{C}x^2-1$ --> $y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-C}{C}x^2-1}$ for $0<C<1$.

Equivalently, $(1-C)x^2-Cy^2=C$ --> $\left(\frac{1}{C}-1\right)x^2-y^2=1$ and this seems like an hyperbola.

Comment: For $C=0$ you get the line $x=0$ and for $C>1$ is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {x^2}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} \ge 0$

$\frac {x^2}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} < \frac {x^2}{x^2} = 1$

$\frac {x^2}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} = C$

if $C = 0$

we get the line $x = 0$

if $0<C<1$

$x^2 = Cx^2 + Cy^2 + C\\
(1-C) x^2 - Cy^2 = C\\
\frac {(1-C)}{C} x^2 - y^2 = 1$

We get a set of hyperbola

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $0\leq C\leq1$ and
$$C = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+1}$$
shows
$$(1-C)x^2-Cy^2=C$$
or
$$\dfrac{1-C}{C}x^2-y^2=1$$
which are hyperbolas centered at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

set $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+1} =k $  we get $\quad (1-k)x^2-ky^2=k$
or
$$\dfrac{1-k}{k}x^2-y^2=1$$

whose level curves (RHS made variable) are parallel straight lines, ellipses or hyperbolas depending on $k$ value.

[image: ContourPlots]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a picture of the contour map:

[image: Contour plot of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+1}]